# Nginx can't catch apple-touch-icon-120x120.png

Tags: nginx, favicon, nginx-location

I have this Nginx config for my static:

```
server {

  location ~ ^/(apple-touch-icon|browserconfig|favicon|mstile)(.*)\.(png|xml|ico)$ {
    root /var/www/static/icons;
  }

  location / {
    uwsgi_pass ...;
  }

}
```

In folder `/var/www/static/icons` I have next icons:

```
-rw-rw-r-- apple-touch-icon-114x114.png
-rw-rw-r-- apple-touch-icon-120x120.png
-rw-rw-r-- apple-touch-icon-144x144.png
-rw-rw-r-- apple-touch-icon-152x152.png
-rw-rw-r-- apple-touch-icon-180x180.png
-rw-rw-r-- apple-touch-icon-57x57.png
-rw-rw-r-- apple-touch-icon-60x60.png
-rw-rw-r-- apple-touch-icon-72x72.png
-rw-rw-r-- apple-touch-icon-76x76.png
-rw-rw-r-- apple-touch-icon.png
-rw-rw-r-- apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
-rw-rw-r-- favicon-160x160.png
-rw-rw-r-- favicon-16x16.png
-rw-rw-r-- favicon-192x192.png
-rw-rw-r-- favicon-32x32.png
-rw-rw-r-- favicon-96x96.png
-rw-rw-r-- favicon.ico
-rw-rw-r-- mstile-144x144.png
-rw-rw-r-- mstile-150x150.png
-rw-rw-r-- mstile-310x150.png
-rw-rw-r-- mstile-310x310.png
-rw-rw-r-- mstile-70x70.png
```

When I try get any of them I get it except `apple-touch-icon-120x120.png`.

Request url `http://my-domain.org/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png` doesn't catch with Nginx rule for favicons and go to rule for uwsgi_pass.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPD**: Nginx main config is default. Ubuntu 16.04. Nginx 1.6.2

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with this. Make sure you're hitting the correct server block.

Comment: Yes, I sure with server block. Other icons return correct.

Comment: Then the answer should be in your error log. All though, there's zero reasons you should be hitting the default location block, unless you have an error_page 404 defined somewhere that points nowhere.

Comment: As an aside, if you are in the "I want *all* icons so I never get annoying 404 in my logs" thing, I advice you to also generate the precomposed touch icons.I advice you to use http://realfavicongenerator.net/ and check everything in the "Assets" tabs. Full disclosure: I'm the author of this tool.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in my hosting provider. They use transparent proxy. With bad config.

I don't know details. But problem was gone after my query in their support.